# List plotting speed vs Numpy array plotting speed

Tags: python, list, performance, numpy, plot

Hello dear stackoverflow users. I have a conceptual question (therefore, no code is necessary). I was wondering if anybody could help me with it, please.
   Assume I have a python list of float numbers and a numpy array of the same numbers. And I want to plot them in matplotlib (against whatever: time or spatial coordinate or anything else - it doesn't matter). I want a 2D plot.
   What will be plotted faster: python list or numpy array?
   Thank you in advance.
   P.S. Just to clarify in case it is an issue. Consider an example: I have data points on velocity of an object vs time. Consider two cases. First, I store velocity data points in a python list and corresponding times in another python list. Then plot them in matplotlib. Second, I store velocity data points in a numpy array and corresponding times in another numpy array. Then plot them in matplotlib. In which of the cases plotting will be done faster?

Origination of the problem lies in my attempt to solve a transient drift-flux model numerically. I had a relatively big amount of steps (time and spatial steps). I used python lists for solution. I didn't use a solver - I wrote my own code. When I tried to plot the data in matplotlib I failed. Matplotlib is too slow. I used pyqtgraph and managed to plot the data. But I want to increase plotting speed even more. That's why I am considering use of numpy arrays.

Comment: Have you tried converting the lists to arrays as you pass them to your plot calls?

Comment: No, I haven't done it yet (due to some reasons) - I've been just pondering about it. That is the question basically. I.e.: do I need to convert my lists to numpy arrays before plotting to speed it up or not; are numpy arrays plotted faster always or there are nuances and so on. @warped answer gave me an interesting insight into it.

Comment: I was guessing that `matplotlib` would convert the lists to arrays before use.  `numpy` functions often do that.  But I can't tell from the source if that's the case. Some quick tests of my own, using `plt.scatter(np.array(x), ...)` got almost as good speed as starting with arrays.  In the past I found that plotting a lot of small lines was much slower than plotting the same data but in long lines.  That has to do with the number of plot objects it has to create.

Answer (score 2):

Testing in IPython:

```
np.random.seed(123)

# arrays:
a = np.random.randint(0,1000,10000)
b = np.random.randint(0,1000,10000)

%%timeit -r 10 -n 10
plt.scatter(a, b)
plt.close()
54.7 ms ± 1.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

# lists
c = [f for f in a]
d = [f for f in b]

%%timeit -r 10 -n 10
plt.scatter(c, d)
plt.close()

154 ms ± 5.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Looks like plotting arrays is faster here.

Testing more cases, with different lengths:

```
         #length|mean|sd
lists = [
         (10000, 154, 5.07),
         (1000, 33 , 0.235),
         (100, 21, 0.198),
         (10, 19.4, 0.937)
         ]
arrays = [
         (10000, 54.7, 1.43), 
         (1000, 21.8, 1.51),
         (100,18.4, 1.16),
         (10, 18.1, 1.87)
         ]

# convert to arrays... for faster plotting ;)
lists = np.array(lists)
arrays = np.array(arrays)

plt.errorbar(lists[:,0], lists[:,1], yerr=lists[:,2], color = 'orange', label='lists', fmt='o')
plt.errorbar(arrays[:,0], arrays[:,1], yerr=arrays[:,2], color = 'teal', label='arrays', fmt='o')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('length of plotted data')
plt.ylabel('time per plot / ms')
```

[image]

## Edit:

Just saw that you are looking at floats. I redid the experiment with floats, and the results are pretty much the same:

```
#data generation:
np.random.seed(123)
a = np.random.rand(10000) * 1000
b = np.random.rand(10000) * 1000

lists = [
        (10000, 155, 13.6),
        (1000, 33 , 0.443),
        (100, 21, 0.436),
        (10, 19.1, 1.09)
        ]
arrays = [
         (10000, 54.5, 3.24), 
         (1000, 21.6, 1.97),
         (100, 18.6, 1.61),
         (10, 19.4, 1.51)
]
```